# How to display test results on jenkins from results.xml file without running the testcases from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple xml result files collected from different builds and I have to display a consolidated report on jenkins.
Is there any plugin available to perform the above action?

We also tried JUnit plugin, we got the following error:

```
ERROR: Step 'Publish JUnit test result report' failed: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did leafNodes run? For example, D:\jenkins\workspace\test-1\testng-results.xml is 14 min old
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check the timestamp when the junit report was generated and last execution time of jenkins job. Both timestamp should match.
If you see a difference, delete the report and re-generate the report.